# Correct Pip location on MacOS

Tags: python, pip, macos-big-sur

I removed all non default MacOs python installations but still there are multiple pip versions in `/usr/local/bin/` folder. Is this correct or broken state?

```
% which pip

/usr/local/bin/pip

% which pip3

/usr/bin/pip3

% which python

/usr/bin/python

% which python3

/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to resolve, but most likely, you have `python 2` and `python 3`, which gives you `pip` and `pip3`. Python 2 is installed by default on your system. If you remove it, there may be issues. Have a try (therefore I would say, it is correct).

Comment: Python goes hand in hand with its version of pip.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to say for certain, because we do not know the history of your system. However, most likely:

- `/usr/bin/python` is the ancient Python 2 that comes with macOS.
- `/usr/bin/python3` is the Python 3 that comes with Xcode.
- `/usr/bin/pip3` goes with the previous item.

This leaves `/usr/local/bin/pip`, which looks like a left-over from some previous installation.

Comment: Is it safe that I remove /usr/local/bin/pip file

Comment: Again, impossible to say with absolute certainty, but probably: yes.